# Angular Interface - can't resolve all parameters for component

Tags: angular

I have a component and I want to implement an interface. However, this doesn't seem to be working. When I hover over `@Component` in Visual Studio Code, I get an error indicating that it can't resolve all parameters for component.

Here is what is looks like:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reaction',
  templateUrl: './reaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reaction.component.scss']
})

export class ReactionComponent implements OnInit, MvReaction {
  @Input() data: MvReaction;
  constructor(
    public id: number, 
    public name:string, 
    public image: string,
    public count: number,
    public selected: boolean) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}

export interface MvReaction{
  id: number,
  name : string,
  image : string,
  count ?: number,
  selected ?: boolean
}
```

And when I use the component, I get:

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ReactionComponent -> Number]: \n
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ReactionComponent -> Number]: \n
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for Number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties should not be set in the constructor. The constructor is reserved for dependencies. You should be doing:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reaction',
  templateUrl: './reaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reaction.component.scss']
})

export class ReactionComponent implements OnInit, MvReaction {
  @Input() data: MvReaction;
  public id: number;
  public name:string;
  public image: string;
  public count: number;
  public selected: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}

export interface MvReaction{
  id: number,
  name : string,
  image : string,
  count ?: number,
  selected ?: boolean
}
```

Comment: In my opinion it is not even necessary to declare them in the class as they will be accessible from `data` object like `data.id, data.name` etc.

Comment: Yes but if you implement an interface like he did (...implements MvReaction {}), then you are required to define the properties, otherwise you will get a compiler error.

Comment: Ah true didn't see that he implements interface

Answer (score -1):

I think that interface properties should be separated by semicolon and should not be in the `constructor` .

Also, are you sure you listed the component in appModule?

Comment: That won't seem to work. I too have added the component to the appModule. Also, this answer would be better suited as a comment. p.s. Not the down voter

Comment: I have rephrased on what you were trying to say. Also now you do have privilege to comment :)..